# Adding a search function to the Android tab bar

Tags: android, mobile, tabs, navigation

We're developing an app on the Android platform. We currently have 3 tabs on the top for navigation. To save on space, it is permissible to add the search icon to the extreme right of the Tab bar on the top? Or does it against the Android Design Guidelines?

Comment: The design guidelines are just that, _guidelines_. Feel free to do whatever you want and ignore them, although your users might not like it if your ui is inconsistent or bad.

Comment: Thanks. I was on the wall about that, but you've helped clear the doubt, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embrace Material Design

With a rounded floating SearchButton at bottom-right of the screen

[Example Image](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsQUxBamxwdy15Vlk/patterns_actions_fab1.png)

Comment: Hm, yes, I'll try that as well.

Comment: I think it's a cool way to solve the problem !! Could you "tick" My answer?